# While finding elements on an array when should I make an else?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, return

I am using a while loop with a counter to find an element on an array. I will check that if the returned element is equal to the lenght of the array the element is not found. The loop is like this.

```
    int i = 0;
    int returned;
    boolean found = false;
    while(i < words.length && !found){
        WordInText check = new WordInText(w);
        if(check.equals(words[i])){
            found = true;
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
   return i
```

What I am wondering if it would be better instead of doing an else on every condition to do the following

```
int i = 0;
    int returned;
    boolean found = false;
    while(i < words.length && !found){
        WordInText check = new WordInText(w);
        if(check.equals(words[i])){
            found = true;
        }
        i++;
   }
   if(!found)
        i++;
   return i-1
```

I feel that the second one is more efficient because it doesn't have to check the condition on every loop and in case that the array was really long it would have to be done a lot. But I'm not sure on when to decide each because the second looks realy ugly and not intuitive.

Comment: Better approach is to use `HashSet<String>` .

Comment: What is `w`, `WordInText`?

Comment: I asked what they are, and you said "yes"...

Comment: @user1803551 Sorry. It is a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple possible refactoring that avoid the question, but I'll try to answer your question as is :

- the `else` costs nothing : it's just a block that will be executed if and only if the `if`'s condition evaluates to `false`.
- it is easily understood by anyone

Even if it doesn't look the prettiest, I see no reason to avoid it. In your second code, not only do you introduce extra instructions, it is also harder to understand since you have to get why the index needs to be increased when the element isn't found.

Answer (score 0):

extract the code in a method, like this

```
public int contains(....) {
  int i = -1;
  while(i < words.length){
     WordInText check = new WordInText(w);
     if(check.equals(words[i])){
         return i;
     }
   i++;
  }
 return i;
}
```

no need for additional variables and clearer structure of the code

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to use an else part or another if condition to check whether its found or not cause you are already checking the condition in while loop.

```
int i = 0;
int returned;
boolean found = false;
while(i < words.length && !found){
    WordInText check = new WordInText(w);
    if(check.equals(words[i])){
        found = true;
    }
    i++;
}
return i;
```

So here the loop will go on until the value of found becomes true (means that till the required element is found. Then in next iteration it will check whether the found value is false. As it's not false anymore the loop will not be executed and the i will be returned. 
There you can check the value of i and decide whether the element is found or not.